# React Native nested stack navigators inside drawer causing infinite useEffect loop on navigation

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-native-navigation

The app I'm working on contains a drawer navigator. I have a stack navigator nested under it.
This stack is composed of 2 different stack navigators to show the user 2 different processes, the booking process and the return process.
Only one if these processes is accessible to the user at a time. So when the user finishes the booking process, I switch to the ReturnProcess.

I am using react-native 0.63.2 , and react-navigation 5

```
// The stack containing the 2 other nested stacks
<BookingStack.Navigator initialRouteName="Booking" screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }} >
    <BookingStack.Screen name="Booking" component={BookingProcess} />
    <BookingStack.Screen name="Return" component={ReturnProcess} />
</BookingStack.Navigator>

  // booking process stack
  function BookingProcess() {
    return (
      <BookingProcessStack.Navigator initialRouteName="Map" screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
        <BookingProcessStack.Screen name="Map" component={MapScreen} />
        <BookingProcessStack.Screen name="CardDetails" component={CreditCardDetailsScreen} /> 
          ... (rest of the screens)
          </BookingProcessStack.Navigator>
        );
      }
    //return process stack
      const ReturnProcess = () => {
        return (
          <ReturnProcessStack.Navigator initialRouteName="MapDirections" screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
            <ReturnProcessStack.Screen name="MapDirections" component={MapDirectionsScreen} />
            <ReturnProcessStack.Screen name="Queue" component={QueueScreen} />
           ...(rest of the screens)
          </ReturnProcessStack.Navigator>
        );
      }
```

And my drawer navigator which holds the stack combining the 2 others:

```
      <UserDrawer.Screen name="Map" options={{
          drawerLabel: () => <Text style={styles.menuItemText}>Map</Text>,
          drawerIcon: () => <Icon type="entypo" name="location-pin" />,
         }}
         component={Booking} />
```

I am using a useEffect hook on the MapScreen which performs an api request, with a cleanup code. However when I navigate to the CreditCardScreen, the CreditCardScreen component keeps rerendering with the errors: could not locate shadow view with tag #17473, this is probably caused by a temporary inconsistency between native views and shadow views, and then maximum depth exceeded. The page flickers until the app crashes

My useEffect hook in the MapScreen, I also tried using useFocusEffect from the react-navigation library, but also did help:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let isMounted = true;
    getDeviceTypes().then(res => {
      //cleanup
      if (isMounted) {
        setDeviceTypes(res.data.data)
        getLocation();
      };

    })
    return () => { isMounted = false }
  }, []);
```

Can someone please help me with this, it has completely stopped my progress for 2 days.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I finally fixed it by moving the BookingProcess and ReturnProcess outside of the Booking method.